# How to get process id, name or status via pipe

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Can I get process id of `ls -al` in below command?

`$ ls -al | echo [I want get process id of left command]`

Thanks

Comment: You probably can't. BTW, what if the left command was a shell builtin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done passing through a file

```
{ ls -al & echo $! > pid;} | { echo $(<pid);}
```

Maybe there is a race condition

With a fifo

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
{ sleep 5 & echo $! >/tmp/fifo;} | { pid=$(</tmp/fifo); echo $pid; ps -p $pid;}
rm /tmp/fifo
```